# Make every functions in all controller execute code some code before execute the functions without add the code in every functions in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a code for checking a session isset or not in **Yii2**, I added the code inside a function in a controller, this is the code

```
if(!isset($session['selectedMonth'])){
        return $this->redirect(['select-period/month']);
        return false;
}
```

I have over than 50 functions in 10 controllers, I want every function use that code, how do I can make it without put that code in every function one by one?

Comment: If all of your controllers extend a common controller, you could add your logic in the `beforeAction`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create base controller for your app, and extend all other controllers from it. Then you could add `beforeAction()` method in this base controller, so it will be used by all controllers that inherit from base controller:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    // initialize $session here

    if(!isset($session['selectedMonth'])){
        Yii::$app->response->redirect(['select-period/month']);
        return false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create simple behavior that will handle ['before action' event](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION-detail), for example:

```
use Yii;
use yii\base\Behavior;
use yii\base\Controller;

class RedirectBehavior extends Behavior
{
    public function events()
    {
        return [
            Controller::EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION => 'beforeAction',
        ];
    }

    public function beforeAction($event)
    {
        if (Yii::$app->session->has('selectedMonth')){
           return;
        }

        Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(['select-period/month'])->send();
     }
}
```

and attach it to your controllers

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'redirect' => [
            'class' => RedirectBehavior::className(),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: inside if condition I set echo 'A';die(); and outside that I set echo 'B';die(); it will print **B** because the session is not set. but if I set exactly like your code, the return doesn't work, it doesn't redirect to *select-period/month*, but if I set `return $this->redirect(['select-period/month']);` it show error **Calling unknown method: app\controllers\RedirectBehavior::redirect()**

Comment: @Blackjack replace `$event->action->controller->redirect(['select-period/month'])` to `Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(['select-period/month'],302)`

Comment: @Blackjack I updated my answer, try to use send() method